# SilverStripe .ico preview

Tags: silverstripe, favicon

It seems SilverStripe is unable to show a preview of .ico files. Is this a framework issue or client code issue?

[image]

The UploadField is added in `SiteConfig`

```
private static $has_one = array(
    'Favicon' => 'Image'
);
```

`$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", UploadField::create('Favicon', 'Favicon'));`

Comment: I've tested this on my local xampp development environment on SilverStripe 3.4 and the `.ico` image appears correctly for me.

Comment: Could be anything... What URL has this little image? It should be resized, so it could be a GD issue, a file permission issue in assets, etc...

Comment: @wmk the filename is `/assets/Uploads/_resampled/FitWzgwLDYwXQ/favicon.ico`. I tried to open the link in the browser -> 404.

Comment: does the file exist on the server?

Comment: @wmk Strangely, no it doesn't! The original upload does (assets/Uploads/favicon.ico) but the one in the UploadField preview pane links to, doesn't. Also, added some extra info to main post

Comment: i _guess_ gd has problems to resize a .ico file?

Comment: @wmk GD = Graphics Draw server application?

Comment: yes. That's my strong gut feeling: SilverStripe does not handle ico files or can generate a preview in another format out of the box. Though i might be wrong...